# Input Button as Input image will not work

Tags: image, button, input

On my website i have a button which when clicked takes you to one of two random youtube videos. However i would like to change this to a image in stead of a button.I have tried to change it to a INPUT type="image" but this doesn't work. Here is the code i am using.

```
         <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
function get_random()
{
var ranNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
return ranNum;
}

function getaGame()
{
var whichGame=get_random();

var game=new Array(2)
game[0]= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=NcFQF3PZFRk#t=722s";
game[1]= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klBAW4MQffU";
location.href = game[whichGame];

}
//-->
</SCRIPT>   


<FORM name="form1"> 

<center> 

<INPUT type="button"  onClick="getaGame()" > 
</center>     

</FORM>


Thanks for any help
```

Comment: First off, your code is very messy. Next, an input does not have a type of 'image'. I think what you're looking for is a link instead of an input button.

Answer (score 0):

An `onclick` event can be fired from any element. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5dY7F/) are some examples!

Comment: Thanks arbitter i have only just started using java script so need to get the hang of it. I changed it to <a href='#' onclick='getaGame()'><img scr="youtube.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="" border="0" align="right"></a> just what ever image i use it will not load

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo here or in your code, but it's `src` and not `scr`. If that's correct, make sure your linking to the image correctly.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer to your question to avoid other people trying to solve this problem while it's already solved.